# How to implement jobs command as shell built-in?

Tags: c++, shell

I'm trying to implement the shell built-in command to get a list of current jobs and their status so the shell outputs something like below.

```
JID  STATUS  COMMAND
1137 Stopped less &
2245 Running cat /dev/urandom | less &
2343 Running ./jobcontrol &
```

Is this best done using waitpid to get the status. How can I keep track of multiple child job IDs from fork?